# DexArchiveMergerException only on release

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, swagger

I developed an app that uses a swagger-generated Java client. The client is in a project called "api", while the app is in a project called "app".

When I build the app via `Build/Make Project` everything works fine. Also, when I try to run the app on an emulated or physical device `Run/Run 'app'`. Running with debugger works as well. Even when I build the project via `Buid/Generate Signed Bundle/APK` and choose the debug option, it works.

Now. The build fails when I try to create a signed release build. The following messages show:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: [...]\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\54, [...]\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\release\0, [...]\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\52.jar, [...]\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\53.jar

---

> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: [...]\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\54, [...]\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\release\0, [...]\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\52.jar, [...]\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\53.jar

---

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

---

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: io.swagger.client.ApiCallback

I am pretty new to developing with Android Studio and Gradle. I tried some solutions on Stack Overflow that already suggested to add some libraries but so far none of them worked with my problem.

To me, its especially suspicious that the last error message points to `io.swagger.client.ApiCallback`.

Could it have anything to do with the fact that both `settings.gradle` for "api" and "app" have the same content? Both look like this:
 `rootProject.name = "swagger-java-client"`. This is the only line in the file, but as far as I know, the `settings.gradle` for "app" already hat that content. I cant remember changing it so its odd to me that it shows "swagger-java-client". Is that normal?

### Update 1

ProGuard has been mentioned in the comments to might be a problem. This is the only occurrence I could find, referencing it. In my `build.gradle` for the "app"-project, there is this part:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

However, removing it did not change anything.

### Update 2

When searching for "io.swagger" AS only finds this:

[image: only one match found]

When searhing for "io.swagger.client.ApiCallback" AS only finds this:

[image: only one match found]

### Update 3

As suggested, I tried adding

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

and adding `android.enableD8 = false` but that didn't help either.

Here are my build.gradle-Files (the first ones that caused the problems, without the suggested corrections I've tried so far.)

build.gradle (Module: api) (generated by Swagger):

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = 'io.swagger'
version = '1.0.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}


if(hasProperty('target') && target == 'android') {

    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 25
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        // Rename the aar correctly
        libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def outputFile = output.outputFile
                if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
                    def fileName = "${project.name}-${variant.baseName}-${version}.aar"
                    output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            def task = project.tasks.create "jar${variant.name.capitalize()}", Jar
            task.description = "Create jar artifact for ${variant.name}"
            task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
            task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
            task.destinationDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/jar")
            task.archiveName = "${project.name}-${variant.baseName}-${version}.jar"
            artifacts.add('archives', task);
        }
    }

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classifier = 'sources'
    }

    artifacts {
        archives sourcesJar
    }

} else {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    install {
        repositories.mavenInstaller {
            pom.artifactId = 'swagger-java-client'
        }
    }

    task execute(type:JavaExec) {
       main = System.getProperty('mainClass')
       classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.21'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

build.gradle (Module: app):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "projectName"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: '../api/build/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    api project(path: ':api')
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
```

Comment: Quick question, does the problem go away when you disable ProGuard? If so, your ProGuard settings need some exclusions adding!

Comment: @JakeSteam as I said, Im pretty new to gradle, but I updated the question to adress ProGuard

Comment: Can you post your gradle file?

Comment: @SharpMobileCode Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question:

What I did was to create the swagger client, move the created folder into my project, adjust the `settings.gradle` file and the `build.gradle` file accordingly.

---

**What went wrong**

The way I configured things, gradle would build the ´api´ project and then the `app` project.
For some reason, when I configured things as `release`, the `app` project referenced the code of the `api` project, as well as the resulting `.jar` file. Thats where the `Program type already present` came from.

---

**How I fixed it**

- Exclude the `api` project from the `app` project
- Build `api` seperately
- Take the resulting `.jar`file and put it in a folder inside your `app` folder called `libs`
- Put this line in your `gradle dependencies` for your `build.gradle (Module: app)`: `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

This included the finished `.jar`file in the `app`project and now I can build release. This should be done regardless, because the swagger client shouldnt be edited anyway, as it is generated code. So even just to not always build that part of the project, this should be done.

However, I still dont fully understand why there is this difference between the `release`and the `debug`build. Would be glad for any insight to that.

---

**EDIT: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I just found out: if, for some reason, I would have wanted to keep the `Module: api` in my project I could have done so by removing the two dependencies in my `Module: app`that start with `implementation fileTree`.
The api-project is already included by the dependency `api project(path: ':api')`. The filetree-lines were the ones causing the problem here, since they were redundant.

However, still no idea why there is a difference between `debug` and `release`

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/448) are some workaround :

- > Can you please make sure you have `multiDexEnabled` set to true as shown below in your gradle settings:

  ```
  android {
      defaultConfig {
          multiDexEnabled true
      }
  }
  ```
- Try `android.enableD8 = false` in **grade.properties**

Comment: Sadly, none of the suggestions have worked. `android.enableD8`even caused AS to issue a warning that its deprecated. Ill add a few more details to the question, as it seems to be a problem many faced. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: io.swagger.client.ApiCallback

Means there are multiple dependencies contain this class, maybe different versions, so you need to exclude them.

1. Press shift twice, search io.swagger, then record the found jar files.
2. If these jar files are simply duplicated, keep 1 in build.gradle.

---

3. If these jar files are modules of other dependency, enter `gradlew -q app:dependencies` in the terminal, find the root dependency names.
4. In build.gradle, choose 1 dependency to keep, for others add exclude command.

For example change

```
implementation 'xxx:xxx'
```

to

```
implementation ('xxx:xxx') { exclude module 'module-name-to-be-excluded' }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Some options to try:

Change build variants of both modules to release, then Build\Build APK

If success, copy the text from Gradle Console.

Next Build\Generate Signed APK...

Compare the text in Gradle Console with the above one to check the difference.

Comment: Im not sure what I am supposed to see here. The console pretty much gets spanned by some ascii trees that look like dependencies, but since I am a rookie, as I mentioned in my original post, I dont really know what to search for.
Also, since its so much text, the terminal is spanned to the extend where part of the output is already overwritten/unreachable. 
When I did 1., only one file appeared. So I guess going for 3. was right. But I dont understand what else you mean here.
I get what "exclude" might do but I dont get what I need to exclude and how to learn what I need to exclude :/

Comment: Only one result in step 1 !? Can you share a screenshot or that file? and do you set different dependency between release and debug?

Comment: The only difference I can see where "release" or "debug" are specifically mentioned in any gradle file is the one i provided but as I said, removing it does not change anything.

Comment: TBH I have no idea at all, I have also tried to create settings.gradle in 2 modules with the same root project name, no problem. I added some other suggestion in my answer may help debugging this issue.

Comment: Im a beginner and dont really know how to apply your suggestion update. Can you break it down a little further and show me exactly what to do?